# Problems in installation of magento on wamp

Tags: magento, wamp

Hello guys can  anyone help me with the issue im having with installation of magento.
my problem is that i have downloaded the magento on wamp and during my installation i got the error and the msg it si giving is FATAL ERROR : Maximum execution time of 60 sec exceeded in
c:\wamp\www\magento\lib\varien\db\adapter\pdo\mysql.php on line 276. plz provide me with the solution any one coz im stuck on this for long enough thanks in advance

Answer (score 5, accepted):

Modify your php.ini with this setting:

```
max_execution_time = 1800
```

I also modify the memory limit allocated to php when using Magento

```
memory_limit = 512M
```

Alternatively you can edit index.php, if you don't have php.ini access.

```
ini_set('max_execution_time ', 1800);
```

Comment: thanks for the answer but still the same problem is there can you tell me is there any other alternative thaks

Comment: it cannot give the SAME error if you modify maximum execution time. if the script reaches the 1800 sec = 30min.. something is wrong with your server configuration.

Answer (score 3):

The exact resolution is as below

This is not an apache or php timed-out message. It really means that the mysql engine timed out. So we will give the mysql some more time to wait until it reports that the operation failed. To make this happen, lets go ahead and change the line with value

**mysql.connect_timeout = 60**

to

**mysql.connect_timeout = -1**

in the **php.ini** file and it will do the trick. The value -1 means unlimited seconds to wait before the mysql connection times out.

Answer (score 1):

HI,

I had the same problem. None of the solutions provided above helped me.

What I did was change both the max_execution_time and max_input_time to 1800. This worked for me. I was able to then get Magento installed.

Answer (score 1):

Change the value of max_input_time in php.ini to a safest value; time is expressed in seconds. Do give a try of 1800
max_input_time = 1800
You would get it worked

Answer (score 0):

If its giving you the same error then it means that you have not changed the settings in php.ini file.

In windows if you install wamp you will have, php.ini in php folder and apache folder.

Make sure that you have modified in both files and restart your server. (I know its strange)

**Try 1**
Browse wamp's root folder and click on phpmyinfo link under tools section.  This will give you the information of your php installation and settings.

look for "Loaded Configuration File", there you will have the location of your exact php.ini file that is used in your wamp installation.

Try to update the Max_execution_time in that file.  Hope this will solve your problem.

Usually, you will not get problems like this.

**Try 2**
May be your antivirus is stopping the request to execute for more than 60 seconds, just trying stopping your anti-virus for a moment and check another time.

I hope this will solve your problems.

Answer (score 0):

I got the same problem, as suggested I did the following changes.

1. ***(wampserver-path)\bin\apache(Apache Version)\bin\php.ini*** - Set the
   value **max_execution_time = 1800**
2. ***(wampserver-path)\bin\php(PHPVersion)\php.ini*** - Set the value
       **max_execution_time = 1800**

But it didn't work. Then I made the next change

- In the ***host/(path-to-magento)/index.php***, just after the opening `<?php`
  tag, added the following. `set_time_limit(1800)`;

> ```
> <?php
> set_time_limit(1800);
> //** Other bunches of code 
> ?>
> ```

Then tried to install a fresh copy. It worked! Hope this helps...