# magento 1.4 very slow on localhost

Tags: magento

I am using magento 1.4 (wamp) . I am facing trouble to save cms pages, it takes approx 10 min to save. Please help.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Install APC, increase php memory to 512 Mb and it will work better. Magento is resource hungry. Also check [other](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/1639213/why-is-magento-so-slow) [posts](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/2757147/2757251#2757251) on the same issue.

Answer (score 2):

If you can, I'd run it on linux. I found saving changes to be much faster and I also ran into some other problems when running on wampserver.

Comment: magento is ONLY supported on linux and you should run it as such

Answer (score 1):

Turn off profiling in Xdebug, as [they say here](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/16313326/wamp-tmp-folder-takes-some-gb-of-space-while-running-magento-in-localhost)

This improved my magento's speed tremendously

Answer (score 0):

Run it on linux. It is giving much better speed there. I too have the same problem with wamp server.