# wamp tmp folder takes some GB of space while running magento in localhost

Tags: magento, wamp, magento-1.7

wamp tmp folder takes some GB's of space while running magento in localhost ,
like this some files  are created in Wamp/tmp folder, while i using magento
cachegrind.out.1367384833
cachegrind.out.1367384834
cachegrind.out.1367384835

file contain code like this

**version: 1

creator: xdebug 2.2.0

cmd: C:\wamp\www\magento\index.php

part: 1

positions: line**

like this it contain some 80k lines in each file
how to solve this problem?
thanks in Advance

Answer (score 51, accepted):

That seems to be due to profiling enabled in Xdebug. Set `xdebug.profiler_enable=0` in your `php.ini` and restart the server to see if it fixes the issue.

Comment: By default it was like this xdebug.profiler_enable = On i've to change "On" to "0"

Comment: @jee try Off as well I suppose... let me know how you go. There are some settings here to try as well: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/5663077/xdebug-and-no-profiling-output

Comment: omg this saved my LIFE! I was struggling with magento being insanely slow, and now that i turned the xdebug profiler off it is at least 3-4 times faster, page loads now take 2-3 seconds instead of 10-15 on localhost. THANK YOU!

Comment: It also helped me to solve such disk space issue in symfony 2 assetic:dump --watch command. Thanks.

Comment: Absolute life saver! Been diabolical how slow my local environment has been!

Comment: Perhaps they changed it but what worked for me in 2023 was to change xdebug.mode to "off". The profiler_enable setting had no effect. Regardless, this pointed me in the right direction and has saved my local environment. Thanks!