# Magento 1.8 is painfully slow on my wamp localhost

Tags: magento, localhost, wampserver, magento-1.8

Magento 1.8 is painfully slow on my wamp localhost.

I **have** increased the memory in `php.ini`, following this [answer](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/2757147/problems-in-installation-of-magento-on-wamp#2757251),

```
max_execution_time = 1800
memory_limit = 512M
```

But it is still very very slow.

Anything else can I do?

Comment: http://www.slideshare.net/grell/magento-performance-optimization-101 check this and this http://www.mgt-commerce.com/blog/magento-on-steroids-best-practice-for-highest-performance/

Comment: Try chnaging the mysql connection from using `localhost` to using `127.0.0.1`

Comment: Probably solvable by having faster hardware. WAMP can be pretty doggy unless it's got some hp underneath.

Answer (score 2):

I have found the same basic behavior.
Have you looked into installing APC plugin into php? Magento benefits greatly from having an opcode cache available.

[Guide](http://blog.lardev.com/2011/07/06/install-apc-on-wamp-server/)

[StackOverflow WAMP/AMP question](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/9916600/installing-php-apc-dll-on-wampserver)

Comment: I haven't installed APC.

Comment: APC does not show on my PHP extension list after installing following this http://blog.lardev.com/2011/07/06/install-apc-on-wamp-server/ I'm on php 5.5

Comment: Late reply, PHP 5.5 has its own built-in opcode cache. I'm not sure how to assist you on that.

Answer (score 1):

I will suggest you to use xampp server it's faster than wamp server.

Comment: is xampp server for windows??

Comment: ya xampp is available for windows also x means it for all Linux, Windows, Mac etc

Comment: WAMPServer and XAMPP are basically the same thing. Switching will probably solve nothing

Comment: Xampp is also Painfully slow

Answer (score 1):

A bit late answering, but might help someone...

I had the same problem with WampServer 10-15 second page load times. I eventually found this post in the wampserver forum  http://forum.wampserver.com/read.php?2,119754

It takes you through setting up wampserver after installation httd.conf, php.ini & my.ini with options for other variables  eg IPv4 or IPv6

It worked for me, page load times dropped to 1 - 2 seconds.